# How should I deal with problems with completed stories in agile

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum

I am new to Agile and scrum and want to ask few things.

Suppose I havetwo user stories `1, 2`

Suppose I finished `story 1` in sprint 1 but while doing `sprint 2` I did something which breaks something so that my things in `user story 1` broken and I need to spend more time on that again.

What do I need to do for that case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either:

**1. You knew you needed to modify Story 1 as part of implementing Story 2.** No problem. Add tasks (under Story 2) as needed to do that work, and consider it part of the Story 2 scope.

**2. You accidentally broke Story 1 during Story 2 works.** Stuff happens. File it as a bug and follow through as you would any other bug.